# p-norm infinity-norm inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm currently studying the Riemann mapping theorem, and since my analysis skills are a bit lacking, I have a question regarding p-norms/infinity-norms.

Given two functions $f \in L^{\infty} (\mathbf{C})$ and $g \in L^p (\mathbf{C}) $, is it true that $\Vert fg \Vert_p \leq \Vert f \Vert_\infty \Vert g \Vert_p$ for $p > 2$. If so, why is this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is in fact true. Just write down the defining integral of the p-norm and try to estimate the integrand

Comment: In a more general situation, you can use Hoelder inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It holds $$|f| \leq \Vert f \Vert_\infty$$ and so $$\Vert fg \Vert_p^p = \int|fg|^p d\lambda \leq \Vert f \Vert_\infty^p \int |g|^p d\lambda = \Vert f \Vert_\infty^p \Vert g \Vert_p^p$$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you